# Use compiler API for type inference

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm trying to use TypeScript's compiler API to perform very basic type inference, but I couldn't find anything helpful from the documentation or google search.

Essentially, I want to have a function `inferType` that takes a variable and return its inferred definition:

```
let bar = [1, 2, 3];
let bar2 = 5;

function foo(a: number[], b: number) {
  return a[0] + b;
}

inferType(bar); // => "number[]"
inferType(bar2); // => "number"
inferType(foo); // "(number[], number) => number"
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this through the compiler API? If not, is there anyway I can achieve this any other way?

Answer (score 6):

You can play with my TypeScript Compiler API Playground example of LanguageService type checking example: https://typescript-api-playground.glitch.me/#example=ts-type-checking-source

Also this is node.js script that parses input typescript code and it infer the type of any symbol according on how it's used. It uses TypeScript Compiler API , creates a Program, and then the magic is just "program.getTypeChecker().getTypeAtLocation(someNode)"

Working example: https://github.com/cancerberoSgx/typescript-plugins-of-mine/blob/master/typescript-ast-util/spec/inferTypeSpec.ts

If you are not familiar with Compiler API start here. Also you have a couple of projects that could make it easier:

- https://dsherret.github.io/ts-simple-ast/
- https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh/dts-dom

good luck

Answer (score 2):

### *Option 1*

You can use the compiler API to achieve this by using an emit transformer. The emit transformer receives the AST during the emit process and it can modify it. Transformers are used internally by the compiler to transform the TS AST into a JS AST. The resulting AST is then written to file.

What we will do is create a transformer that, when it encounters a function named `inferType` it will add an extra argument to the call that will be the typescript type name.

**transformation.ts**

```
import * as ts from 'typescript'
// The transformer factory
function transformer(program: ts.Program): ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> {
    let typeChecker =  program.getTypeChecker();
    function transformFile(program: ts.Program, context: ts.TransformationContext, file: ts.SourceFile): ts.SourceFile {
        function visit(node: ts.Node, context: ts.TransformationContext): ts.Node {
            // If we have a call expression
            if (ts.isCallExpression(node)) {
                let target = node.expression;
                // that calls inferType
                if(ts.isIdentifier(target) && target.escapedText == 'inferType'){
                    // We get the type of the argument
                    var type = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(node.arguments[0]);
                    // And then we get the name of the type
                    var typeName = typeChecker.typeToString(type)
                    // And we update the original call expression to add an extra parameter to the function
                    return ts.updateCall(node, node.expression, node.typeArguments, [
                        ... node.arguments,
                        ts.createLiteral(typeName)
                    ]);
                }
            }
            return ts.visitEachChild(node, child => visit(child, context), context);
        }
        const transformedFile = ts.visitEachChild(file, child => visit(child, context), context);
        return transformedFile;
    }
    return (context: ts.TransformationContext) => (file: ts.SourceFile) => transformFile(program, context, file);
}
// Compile a file
var cmd = ts.parseCommandLine(['test.ts']);
// Create the program
let program = ts.createProgram(cmd.fileNames, cmd.options);

//Emit the program with our extra transformer
var result = program.emit(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, {
    before: [
        transformer(program)
    ]
} );
```

**test.ts**

```
let bar = [1, 2, 3];
let bar2 = 5;

function foo(a: number[], b: number) {
return a[0] + b;
}
function inferType<T>(arg:T, typeName?: string) {
    return typeName;

}
inferType(bar); // => "number[]"
inferType(bar2); // => "number"
inferType(foo); // "(number[], number) => number"
```

**result file test.js**

```
var bar = [1, 2, 3];
var bar2 = 5;
function foo(a, b) {
    return a[0] + b;
}
function inferType(arg, typeName) {
    return typeName;
}
inferType(bar, "number[]"); // => "number[]"
inferType(bar2, "number"); // => "number"
inferType(foo, "(a: number[], b: number) => number"); // "(number[], number) => number"
```

**Note**
This is just a proof of concept, you would need to further test. Also integrating this into your build process might be non trivial, basically you would need to replace the original compiler with this custom version that does this custom transform

### *Option 2*

Another option would be to use the compiler API to perform a transformation of the source code before compilation. The transformation would insert the type name into the source file. The disadvantage is that you would see the type parameter as a string in the source file, but if you include this transformation in your build process it will get updated automatically. The advantage is that you can use the original compiler and tools without changing anything.

**transformation.ts**

```
import * as ts from 'typescript'

function transformFile(program: ts.Program, file: ts.SourceFile): ts.SourceFile {
    let empty = ()=> {};
    // Dummy transformation context
    let context: ts.TransformationContext = {
        startLexicalEnvironment: empty,
        suspendLexicalEnvironment: empty,
        resumeLexicalEnvironment: empty,
        endLexicalEnvironment: ()=> [],
        getCompilerOptions: ()=> program.getCompilerOptions(),
        hoistFunctionDeclaration: empty,
        hoistVariableDeclaration: empty,
        readEmitHelpers: ()=>undefined,
        requestEmitHelper: empty,
        enableEmitNotification: empty,
        enableSubstitution: empty,
        isEmitNotificationEnabled: ()=> false,
        isSubstitutionEnabled: ()=> false,
        onEmitNode: empty,
        onSubstituteNode: (hint, node)=>node,
    };
    let typeChecker =  program.getTypeChecker();
    function visit(node: ts.Node, context: ts.TransformationContext): ts.Node {
        // If we have a call expression
        if (ts.isCallExpression(node)) {
            let target = node.expression;
            // that calls inferType
            if(ts.isIdentifier(target) && target.escapedText == 'inferType'){
                // We get the type of the argument
                var type = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(node.arguments[0]);
                // And then we get the name of the type
                var typeName = typeChecker.typeToString(type)
                // And we update the original call expression to add an extra parameter to the function
                var argument =  [
                    ... node.arguments
                ]
                argument[1] = ts.createLiteral(typeName);
                return ts.updateCall(node, node.expression, node.typeArguments, argument);
            }
        }
        return ts.visitEachChild(node, child => visit(child, context), context);
    }

    const transformedFile = ts.visitEachChild(file, child => visit(child, context), context);
    return transformedFile;
}

// Compile a file
var cmd = ts.parseCommandLine(['test.ts']);
// Create the program
let host = ts.createCompilerHost(cmd.options);
let program = ts.createProgram(cmd.fileNames, cmd.options, host);
let printer = ts.createPrinter();

let transformed = program.getSourceFiles()
    .map(f=> ({ o: f, n:transformFile(program, f) }))
    .filter(x=> x.n != x.o)
    .map(x=> x.n)
    .forEach(f => {
        host.writeFile(f.fileName, printer.printFile(f), false, msg => console.log(msg), program.getSourceFiles());
    })
```

**test.ts**

```
let bar = [1, 2, 3];
let bar2 = 5;
function foo(a: number[], b: number) {
    return a[0] + b;
}
function inferType<T>(arg: T, typeName?: string) {
    return typeName;
}
let f = { test: "" };
// The type name parameter is added/updated automatically when you run the code above.
inferType(bar, "number[]");
inferType(bar2, "number"); 
inferType(foo, "(a: number[], b: number) => number"); 
inferType(f, "{ test: string; }");
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Just to clarify I'm planning to use this feature in my Node JS application, not as part of the build process. Option 1 sounds more suitable to my case. Besides, I can control from my own code that I'll pass to `inferType` only one variable or the definition of that variable in source code (such that it has more context, which is especially useful for inferring type of a function).

Comment: @benjaminz I'm not quite sure I understand how you will be using it in your node application. If the application is written in Typescript, and you want your code to use a function such as `inferType`, to use the compiler api, you will need to execute the code above at build time (when you app code get converted from ts to js) At runtime the compiler API no be available

Comment: you can use compiler API at run time per doc: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API . What I'm trying to achieve is to leverage TypeScript's type inference capability in my Node application.

Comment: @benjaminz You can use it to compile code.. you can use it to recompile your own code but that will not impact executing code. The only way to get the full name of the type is to do so at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway I can achieve this through the compiler API

The compiler API can let you inspect *code* when *code is a string*. e.g.

```
const someObj = ts.someApi(`
// Code 
let bar = [1, 2, 3];
let bar2 = 5;

function foo(a: number[], b: number) {
  return a[0] + b;
}
`);
// use someObj to infer things about the code
```

> If not, is there anyway I can achieve this any other way?

Use `typeof` although its [significantly limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Alternatively load *self* code using nodejs `__filename` (will only work in node and only if running thought `ts-node` i.e. raw TS ): https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_filename.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use decorators.

```
function inspectType(target: Object, propKey: string): any {
}

class MyClass {
    @inspectType foo: number;
    @inspectType elem: HTMLElement;
}

console.info(Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", Object.getPrototypeOf(MyClass), "foo")); // Constructor of the Number
console.info(Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", Object.getPrototypeOf(MyClass), "elem")); // Constructor of the HTMLElement
```

Note, to make it work its needed enable options in config:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
}
```

And use [reflect-metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata) polyfil. More details on decorators in [my article (rus)](https://habrahabr.ru/company/docsvision/blog/310870/).